# how to link local pages with flags in submenu

Tags: links, translation, sub-menu

we have 4 flags on our website in the submenu. two, german and english are leading to the internal translation (wpml) the other two (chinese and russian) are leding to external links (local copies of the page on russian / chinese server). Now I am trying to edit this flags. however, I can't find where to edit them.

Comment: Are you checked menus page (Dashboard -> Apprentice -> Menus ) at Dashboard?

Comment: I did, it seems not to be related to the menu. I have deleted the menu and its still there